# Debugging WPF bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a project with others that uses C# and XAML. I am trying to clean up some of our binding warnings.

But I keep getting a runtime warning that reads:

> System.Windows.Media.Animation Warning: 6 :
>
> Unable to perform action
> because the specified Storyboard was never applied to this object for
> interactive control.;
>
> Action='Remove';
>
> Storyboard='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>
> Storyboard.HashCode='99999999';
>
> Storyboard.Type='System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard';
>
> TargetElement='System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter';
>
> TargetElement.HashCode='99999999';
>
> TargetElement.Type='System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter'

How do I debug this? There are numerous calls to remove a storyboard throughout the project and I don't know which has the given hashcode.

This is not an open source project so publishing the source is out of the question.

Comment: 99999999 seems like a very unlikely hash code. Could you set a breakpoint on each remove and see which causes the debug line to be written?

Comment: Try using a tool like [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). I frequently end up using it to debug WPF bindings

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can debug Bindings using a "DebugConverter" that just returns the value.

```
public class DebugConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, 
       object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would agree, though it looks like the OP doesn't actually have a binding problem. He just can't remove a storyboard.